# What the resetiosflags(ios::skipws) does?

Tags: c++, string

Cand someone explain me? I am learning about char vectors in c++ and thus command poped up. Please explain it for a very low grade guy

Comment: "Command poped up"? What do you mean by that? Popped up *where*? Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if possible and relevant (which is almost always), please create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: There is a very good free C++ reference that you should consider reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From cppreference on [std::resetiosflags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/resetiosflags):

> clears all format flags of the stream out or in as specified by the mask

This refers to one way input and output can be handled in C++, with stateful IO streams. If you construct a stream object (e.g. `std::stringstream`) and write formatted output to it, you can change the way this particular stream object handles the formatting by IO manipulators. This might be convenient, but comes with the drawback that these options might be undesired at a later point. That's where such a method comes in handy. Have a look at the example part of the above cppreference link.

As a side note, as you said "I am learning about char vectors", you might want to forget about IO manipulation for the moment and revisit that chapter later. `std::vector<char>` or `std::string` are objects that can be used and understood without delving into the `<iostream>` facilities.